# xpath with multiple criterias over siblings and position

Tags: xml, xpath

I have following xml document. I want to extract the value of the Child Data with name='Category' and value='bb' which following-sibling name='WayPointNumber'. 
I have tried somthing like this:

```
//Data[[@name='Category' and ./value='bb'] and [/following-sibling::*[(@name='WayPointNumber')]]]/ExtendedData/Data[5]
```

But i always get an error: ERROR - Failed to evaluate XPath expression: Unexpected token "[" in path expression

How is the correct syntax?

```
<root>
 <ExtendedData>
      <Data name="Tournumber">
        <value>1</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="Guide">
        <value>lago di garda</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="Category">
        <value>Numbering</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="Category">
        <value>bb</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="WayPointNumber">
        <value>13</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="Type">
        <value>POI</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="Hashlink">
        <value>1_822606</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="LocalId">
        <value>822606</value>
      </Data>
 </ExtendedData>
 <ExtendedData>
      <Data name="Tournumber">
        <value>1</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="Guide">
        <value>lago di garda</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="Category">
        <value>Numbering</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="WayPointNumber">
        <value>14</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="Type">
        <value>POI</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="Hashlink">
        <value>1_822557</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="LocalId">
        <value>822557</value>
      </Data>
 </ExtendedData>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to extract the value of the Child Data with name='Category' and value='bb' which following-sibling name='WayPointNumber'.

I think you are making this too complicated. Use the following path expression:

```
/root/ExtendedData/Data[@name = 'Category' and value = 'bb' and following-sibling::Data[@name = 'WayPointNumber']]
```

Evaluate the XPath expression, e.g. with the `xpath` command in a bash shell:

```
$ xpath a.xml '/root/ExtendedData/Data[@name = "Category" and value = "bb" and following-sibling::Data[@name = "WayPointNumber"]]'
```

Then, the result will be:

```
Found 1 nodes:
-- NODE --
<Data name="Category">
  <value>bb</value>
</Data>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i am getting weired about the xpath syntax when i try to extract the WayPointNumber. I tried the following syntax with no success. Can you give me an advice one more time? /root/ExtendedData/Data[@name = 'WayPointNumber' and  following-sibling::Data[@name = 'Category'] and following-sibling::Data/value='bb']/value

Comment: unbelievable, i solved it on my own, i think i got it now. The solution is:  /root/ExtendedData/Data[@name='WayPointNumber' and preceding-sibling::Data[@name = 'Category' and  value='bb']].   YIPPIE!!

Comment: @happymapper You are welcome. I don't understand what you have asked in your comment, though. But feel free to open a new question - and make it very clear what you are looking for.